# Return a sql/postGIS created view via GraphQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql, postgis, geojson

For a project for the municipality we are creating an api.
We've chosen GraphQL as framework for the API and we've written it in C#.
The API works for normal data like strings, ints etc.
However there is a catch. We need to work with Geometry/spatial data as well. So we've 'linked' the GraphQL API to our database, which is a PostGIS/PostgreSQL database.
We want GeoJSON as output, because that is easily plottable using something like MapBox.

The view we've created within PostGIS/PostgreSQL is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW pandGeoJSON AS
select row_to_json(fc)
from (
    select
        'FeatureCollection' as "type",
        array_to_json(array_agg(f)) as "features"
    from (
        select
            'Feature' as "type",
            ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) :: json as "geometry",
            (
                sor_id,
                status
            ) as "properties"
        from pand INNER JOIN sor as s on pand.sor_id = s.sor_pandid
        group by sor_id
    ) as f 
) as fc;
```

But I can't seem to find anywhere on the internet how we would be able to get that view and use it as output of our GraphQL API. Or are we thinking the wrong way round and should we create that view within GraphQL itself?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is quite simple. You can just call the view the same way you call a table. So you have to create them the same way as well.

Quite easy, still, if you didn't know it, you didn't know it. Finding the answer is very helpfull in those instances.